# How to not send mule headers in soap request and response

Tags: mule

I have a request-response `http endpoint` defined as follows:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint address="${mvi.service.address}" exchange-pattern="request-response">
   <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:mvi.wsdl" namespace="http://pennmutual.com/services/mvi" service="MVIService" />
</http:inbound-endpoint>
```

The response it sends back to the client has the mule header appended like below:

```
 <soap:Header>
  <mule:header xmlns:mule="http://www.muleumo.org/providers/soap/1.0">
     <mule:MULE_CORRELATION_ID>4784545a-4fad-44ac-171e-1bc150ccdcb2</mule:MULE_CORRELATION_ID>
     <mule:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE>-1</mule:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE>
     <mule:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE>-1</mule:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE>
  </mule:header>
```

How can I get rid of the `<mule:header>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"
```

on your `cxf:proxy-service`. And also add a global CXF configuration element:

```
<cxf:configuration enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"/>
```

Comment: I am testing with SoapUI and still see mule header coming in <soap:Header> element

Comment: Apologies I forgot the global CXF config element. Try again.

Comment: Thanks, works this time. Curious how does global CXF configuration element works, its not referred by <cxf:proxy-service> element.

Comment: Like transports, security manager, etc... if there's only one, no need to refer to it, it's going to be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way to remove the Mule headers by using `cxf:outInterceptors` and java class as follows :-

```
<http:inbound-endpoint address="${mvi.service.address}" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
<cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:mvi.wsdl" namespace="http://pennmutual.com/services/mvi" service="MVIService" >
<cxf:outInterceptors >
  <spring:bean id="outfault" class="com.SOAPInterceptorOutboundHeaderRemover"/>
</cxf:outInterceptors> 
</cxf:proxy-service>
```

And in your SOAPInterceptorOutboundHeaderRemover java class :-

```
public class SOAPInterceptorOutboundHeaderRemover extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

public SOAPInterceptorOutboundHeaderRemover() {
super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage arg0) throws Fault {
List<Header> headerList = arg0.getHeaders();
Header muleHeader = null;
boolean isMuleHeader = false;
for (Header header : headerList) {
ElementNSImpl element = (ElementNSImpl) header.getObject();
if ("mule:header".equals(element.getNodeName())) {
isMuleHeader = true;
muleHeader = header;
}
}
if (isMuleHeader) {
arg0.getHeaders().remove(muleHeader);
}

}
}
```

This `cxf:outInterceptors` java class  the Mule headers from the response and is working fine